# silverlight-how to open grid details in a new page

Tags: silverlight

This is the scenario

I have a page  page1 which has a grid and bound to the data(columns:id name,adress).

The requirement is if i click on on of the id displayed in grid it should open a new page(page2) with textboxes displaying the details of the cliked id(name,address here) .Then i edit the page and save the data.Then clicking on return button i should be able to naviagte to the previous page(Page1) Here again the grid should display the latest data(edited in the second page).

Since silverlight page rendering is like usercontrol ,this task is little confusing for me.

i appreciate some one can provide a solution for this ?(Its will be good if code samples given)

Thanks in Advance

SC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1.) You might want to look into using the either the DataGrid or [the free AgDataGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Grid/).  They are both much eaiser to use than the default grid.

2.) To get the kind of functionality you are talking about is easy. The text box has a MouseLeftButtonUp event that corresponds to a click.  Once you have this, you can get the DataContext of your TextBox and this will be your object.  Just pass that on to the second page, and you'll be good.  Any changes you make on the second page will be automatically reflected on the first page.

3.) To learn how to create navigation in Silverlight 2, [Watch this video](http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=56933)